# Duplicating MapKit annotation functionality on a generic UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, annotations, mapkit

I am trying to develop something similar to Google Maps, without using the MapKit framework. Is it possible to create annotations for a custom `UIScrollView`?
I did search for it , but could not find the solution. 
I want to use the annotation technique to mark the pin as a flag on the custom image which I use.

Comment: Why not leverage MapKit and simply provide your own map tiles?

Comment: But I am not using google maps to create my tiles. I have tiles of different images and want to place an annotation field on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe custom tiles would be your best option. You may want to peek at the following projects:

https://github.com/mattrajca/MapKit

https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo

Comment: How do we add this line without using MKMapView: [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

Comment: I don't understand. You're trying to not include MapKit at all? If so, why? You should be able to leverage the work Apple's already done.

Comment: I do not want to add pins on google maps but a different custom made tile map like floor plan of apartments in which I can show a pin on top of the bathroom or restroom or the apartment canvas on which when the user click he gets all the information.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a UIImageView with an image of a pin to the UIImageView of the floor plan inside the scroll view.

if you add it to the UIImageView, when you pan or zoom, it will stay at that location.

if you add a UIControl (or make it a button instead of an UIImageView) which can react to a touch and show a text field or title or something.

its gonna have to be all custom.